# S3 Bucket policy: "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file" during s3client.listObjects()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to add access to listObjects action to bucket policy to get read from s3, receive an error:

> Error Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

```
{
           "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
           "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::<ID>:user/my_user"},
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::outputbucket/*",
           "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["folder/*"]}}

        }
```

What is wrong with policy?

**UPD**
Delete "/*" in Resource and Condition at all, and receive an error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.

```
           {
               "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
               "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::<ID>:user/my_user"},
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::outputbucket"
            }
```

Failed in this code:

```
ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(outputBucketName, outputKeyPrefix);
```

> > Request processing failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to parse XML document with
> >     handler class
> >     com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler]
> >     with root cause
>
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.     at
>   org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
>   ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>   ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>   ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>   ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown
>   Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>   ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>   ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>   ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>   ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:142)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseListBucketObjectsResponse(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:298)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:70)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:59)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:62)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:31)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.http.response.AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.java:70)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1503)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1226)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4169)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4116)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4110)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:819)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:797)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]

Comment: Can you remove `/*` in the resource and try? ListBucket action only works for listing buckets and not the objects inside them. /* indicates objects within a bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Answer my own question. 
As mentioned in https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=160117 problem was with bucketName. I used path to bucketName + folder, but shout be only bucket name

- com.example.bucketName/folder <- wrong
- com.example.bucketName/       <- correct

  ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
                      .withBucketName("com.example.bucketName/")
                      .withPrefix("folder/")